# Regarding contract file publishing issue with Pactbroker i.e Pactflow

Tags: microservices, pact

I am working on microservices contract testing with Pact and was executing consumer micro service file  with Pactflow as the publisher to provider and when i was executing the consumer file the contract file is not getting published to Pactbroker i.e Pactflow from which provider has to pick when it executes

Pre-requisites:

1.In pom.xml, my pactflow configuration is like below:

```
    <configuration>
    <pactBrokerUrl>pactflow url</pactBrokerUrl>
    <pactBrokerToken>API token to get from Pactflow</pactBrokerToken>
    </configuration>
```

2.Under PactProviderTest file,i have annotation like this:

@PactBroker(url="pact url",
authentication= @PactBrokerAuth(token="API token to get from pactflow"))

Please let me know with the resolution for this

Thank you,
Shiva